# Prevent Scrolling with Mouse Wheel in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scroll, mousewheel

I want to prevent a panel from scrolling when the mousewheel is used. I've tried setting the flag `Handled` on the `HandledMouseEventArgs` to `false`, but that doesn't work.

In this repro code, we have one panel and one button.

```
using (var scrollTestForm=new Form())
{
    var panel = new Panel() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    scrollTestForm.Controls.Add(panel);
    var buttonOutsideArea = new Button();
    buttonOutsideArea.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(panel.Width * 2, 100);
    panel.Controls.Add(buttonOutsideArea);
    panel.AutoScroll = true;
    panel.MouseWheel += delegate (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = false;
    };
    scrollTestForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

When using the mouse wheel, the panel scrolls. How can I prevent it from scrolling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create your custom control and [WM_MOUSEWHEEL message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousewheel)

So first create a new panel

```
    public class PanelUnScrollable : Panel
    {       
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {           
            if(m.Msg == 0x20a) return; 
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

**Edit**, or if you want to control is scrollable or not(and then in your main panel you can call `panel.ScrollDisabled = true`);

```
    public class PanelUnScrollable : Panel
    {
        public bool ScrollDisabled { get; set; }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x20a && ScrollDisabled) return;             
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

Then use it in your original form

```
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CreateNewUnscrollablePanel();            
        } 

        public void CreateNewUnscrollablePanel()
        {
           using (var unScrollablePanel = new UnScrollablePanel() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill })
            {                     
                this.Controls.Add(unScrollablePanel);
                var buttonOutsideArea = new Button();
                buttonOutsideArea.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(unScrollablePanel.Width * 2, 100);
                unScrollablePanel.Controls.Add(buttonOutsideArea);
                unScrollablePanel.AutoScroll = true;
                unScrollablePanel.ScrollDisabled = true; //-->call the panel propery
                unScrollablePanel.MouseWheel += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) //--> you dont need this
                {
                    ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
                };

                this.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

Comment: To be *precise*, you should set `m.WParam = IntPtr.Zero; m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;` and let `base.WndProc` get through.

Comment: @Jimi can you explain why?

Comment: `WParam` set to `IntPtr.Zero` will change the carrier content, saying *no wheel rotation happened*. `m.Result = IntPtr.Zero` is the standard result when this message has been processes. Letting `base.WndProc` through preserves the mouse location that `lParam` is referencing.